# Remove gravity from single body

Tags: box2d, andengine

I have multiple bodies in my game world in andengine. All the bodies affected by gravity but in that I want my specific body does not affected by the gravity.

For that solution after research I found that I have to use 
`body.setGravityScale(0)`
method for my problem solution.

But in my andengine extension I don't found that method so please provide guidance about how get access about that method.

Also for the above problem any other guidance will be acceptable. Thank You!

I apply following code for reverse gravity
`final Vector2 vec = new Vector2(0, -SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH
                * bulletBody.getMass());`

`bulletBody.applyForce(vec, bulletBody.getWorldCenter());`

Comment: I manually update the andengine box2d library and add setGravityScale() method that is the way I do my work.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a version of Box2D that does not provide the `SetGravityScale` method, the best option is to disable gravity entirely and manually apply *gravity itself* to all but one object.

Applying the opposite of gravity is not significantly more expensive, but it is often unusably imprecise when multiple forces are acting on the same object.

It is also possible you may want to make bullets kinematic objects rather than dynamic ones. This will stop them from being affected by gravity, and allow you to move them by setting their velocity rather than applying forces, often a more useful approach for a bullet. If you do this, however, they will no longer interact with static objects either.

Comment: how can I apply gravity to particular object manually because there was no method for manual gravity setting

Comment: hint: gravity is a force

Answer (score 2):

To make bodies "immune" to gravity simply apply an equal and opposite force for every step. Opposite forces will cancel each other out, leaving you with zero force (no gravity). This method means your object will still react to other forces.

Alternatively you can set the mass of the object to zero. Massless objects are not affected by gravity. However the second option may have some unintended consequences. Some physics engines make things with zero mass static. Which means they don't respond to collisions either (you'd likely not want such an interaction with a massless object anyways).

Comment: You are wrong about one thing - AndEngine uses the C++ version of Box2D, it is not a Java port.

Comment: Good to know. The documentation is pretty poor for AndEngine.

Comment: Chances are, applying an opposite force will take twice as long though.

Comment: @Tharwen Twice as long to do what? The engine is going to sum up the forces before it does anything else. I can't imagine this would add more than a millisecond or two. Which is negligible.

Comment: Applying two forces will probably take twice as long as applying one force. It's just something to be aware of, and it will stop being negligible if you start doing the calculation thousands of times or more (Admittedly, it's unlikely that you would, but as I said, it's just something to be aware of).

Comment: Applying opposite force on every step does not do my thing correct. The moving body show abnormal behavior like when I fire bullet it moves down word as it goes long.

Comment: @Siddharth: What force exactly are you applying? AndEngine uses fairly precise gravity constant. Please modify the question and show us the code you use.

Comment: Also provide guidance for accessing new method setGravityScale(). So my work became easier. New box2d library included this.

Comment: @Byte56: I hope you meant "a _microsecond_ or two" - a millisecond would be both unexpectedly expensive for summing forces, and not negligible in the context of a game loop.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Indeed I did. Since it's essentially just adding floats. Which modern processors can do in a few cycles or less.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I update my library of andengine with setGravityScale() method update. If any one require help can mail me at siddharth3322@gmail.com

Comment: Zero mass also has side effects during collision response. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Elastic_collisions

Comment: Don't know about other versions but in the andengine version of Box2d zero density objects are affected by gravity and so can't be used as a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *kinematic* bodies is what you want, notice they are not affected by collision response.